# Trying to SSH to remote server from VM Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I need to ssh into a remote server. I set up a fresh Ubuntu install in VirtualBox for that purpose.

First of all I generated my public key:

`ssh-keygen -b -4096`

Then tried to ssh:

`ssh remote_user@remote_server`

But I am getting the following error:

```
remote_user@remote_server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Not sure what I am missing.

edit: I ran `ssh-copy-id remote_user@remote_server` and got the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
remote_user@remote_server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: After you generated your public/private key pair, did you actually _install_ the public key onto the remote host (e. g. `ssh-copy-id user@host.example.com`?)

Comment: @DopeGhoti do you mean I should install it in my VM local machine? I just tried doing it and got some other error messages.

Comment: Is the remote server a cloud VM?  Who administers it?

Comment: @Jesse_b it's Digital Ocean I believe.

Comment: @dabadaba: You must upload the key to your account on the digital ocean portal.  Instructions can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-account/)

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you. I'll let the corresponding person know and I'll come back if problems persist, hopefully not.

Comment: Did you make sure that `PubkeyAuthentication` was enabled on your SSH server?  Did you make sure to create a key pair that would be accepted by the SSH server?Recent SSH does not allow `dsa` keys anymore, but running the command you posted gave me an `rsa` key pair which should work by default if `PubkeyAuthentication` is enabled

Comment: @GracefulRestart not sure if it's enabled, running `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep PubkeyAuthentication` produces an empty result. As of the encryption algorithm, I used the default one which is RSA.

Comment: @dabadaba: `grep -n PubkeyAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  The `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file is for the client and not the server.

Comment: @GracefulRestart right, I just realized you meant the server. Well, I have no access to the server so I couldn't know. I assume that is the problem then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to configure key based authentication on your remote server you need to actually add your key to it.

You can do that using `ssh-copy-id` which is available on most distributions with the following syntax:

```
ssh-copy-id remote_user@remote_server
```

Note: You will need to know `remote_user`'s password to complete this.

It will then look for your `id_rsa.pub` file and add it to the remote server's `authorized_keys` file.

If you saved your key to somewhere other than `id_rsa.pub` you can specify this location using:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/custom_key.pub remote_user@remote_server
```

---

Otherwise you can log into `remote_server` via some other means (password login) and manually add the contents of your public key into the `authorized_keys` file.

This file is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

You can use the following command to perform this from your ubuntu vm (again as long as you have `remote_user`'s password:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@remote_host "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

---

Many cloud providers require you upload the key to your account on their web portal to have it added to the machine's authorized_keys file.  They often block other methods of making this change.

In the case of Digital Ocean you must follow the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-account/).

Comment: I do have the `remote_user`'s password but I am getting an error when runnin `ssh-copy-id`. Check out my edit. And yes, the keys are in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.